# Is there an easy way to stream a m3u in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, media

I can have a UIWebView with the .m3u file opened, which will go to the webview with a play button displayed, and that automatically goes to the quicktime player and starts playing the stream.  But when I press the done button, it goes back to the UIWebView with a little play button in the middle, and from there you can go back to the previous screen (it was selected from a tableview).  So I just want it to automatically load the quicktime player in the view.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [m3u file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) is nothing more than a text file listing MP3 (and / or other format) digital audio files to be interpreted by player software as a series of audio files to be played in succession. So my best guess (I am about to implement this myself, so I'll find out soon if it actually works that way) at going about this is:

read in m3u file

parse for stream URLs and store these

choose / let user decide which one to play

Implement streaming player like explained [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html).

There is no step 5. I hope.